# Excel VBA - Place Data Validation in a cell if it is not filled with color

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I am trying to add a Data Validation to cells that are *not* filled with color. With the code I've tried (see below), for some reason it still adds the Data Validation to every cell in the range, even if they are filled with a color.

Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub Data_Validation()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet
Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range
Dim c As Range

Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List")

'these are two cells in column A, but they may change position if rows are added, so I named them. 
Set Range1 = WS.Range("DV_Start:DV_End") 

'This is the named range for cells on the List worksheet:
Set Range2 = WS2.Range("ListCells")

For Each c In Range1

    If c.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then

    Else

        With Range1.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                Formula1:="='" & WS2.Name & "'!" & Range2.Address
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = "Name"
            .ErrorTitle = "ERROR: Invalid"
            .InputMessage = "Please enter or select something..."
            .ErrorMessage = "What you have entered is invalid. Please try again."
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `If c.Interior.PATTERN <> xlNone Then`

Comment: `With C.Validation`

Comment: Hi Jeeped! That fixed it!! Thanks so much :)

Comment: Can we just chalk this up to a typo or would you rather a formal response below?

Comment: @mitchmitch24 You can also get rid of that `Else` and just make your `If` line `If Not c.Interior.ColorIndex <> xl None Then`

Comment: Hi Jeeped, I was not familiar with .interior code until today, so this is all pretty new. I summed up your comments in an answer though! Thanks again!

Comment: Hi dwirony, I've been seeing the if not none then statements lately, but I am still struggling to understand- is it simply a way to shorten if then else statements? Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

As per Jeeped's comments:

Changing the `c.interior.colorindex` to `c.interior.pattern` and changing the `Range.Validation` to `c.validation`

got it working. Thanks again to Jeeped!